# How to recover grub2?

Tags: grub2

I installed Ubuntu 11.10 and then after that, I upgraded my Lubuntu 10.10 to 11.04. The grub2 initiated through the installation overwrote the grub written by Ubuntu. After that, I can't find any boot entries leading to Ubuntu or Windows 7 in the grub menu. How do I recover the grub2 which has all the menus?

Here are the outputs for **update-grub** and **fdisk -l**

**update-grub** :

```
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.38-11-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.38-11-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-22-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.35-22-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
```

**fdisk -l**

```
Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x65728979

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1          13      102400   de  Dell Utility
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda2   *          13        1288    10240000    7  HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sda3            1288        8937    61440000    7  HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sda4            8937       38914   240786311    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5            8937       33999   201311607+   7  HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sda6           36442       38805    18979840   83  Linux
/dev/sda7           38805       38914      872448   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda8           33999       36334    18751488   83  Linux
/dev/sda9           36334       36442      863232   82  Linux swap / Solaris
Partition table entries are not in disk order
```

Comment: The next time you are here looking to overwrite Lubuntu's grub, do this: `sudo grub-install /dev/sda` And don't forget to thank Takkat and aking1012.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just boot into Lubuntu and from the command line:

```
update-grub2
```

Check the output from the command and make sure all your distros are there. 
If not then try:

```
grub-install /dev/sda
update-grub2
```

More information can be found in this [dual-booting guide](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/09/dual-booting-guide-pdf-windows-and.html)

Comment: Thanks for your time. 

After posting this question, I found a similar question which led me to install os-prober. After installing it and finding that all the menus are available in the grub, I removed the 30_os_prober something file from the /etc/grub.d directly. Now, if I try to reinstall the os-prober, it still doesn't provide the desirable result.

I tried your solution but it doesn't list all of the distros. Thanks again!

Comment: I don't know what I did but somehow all the distros are suddenly available in the grub boot menu. Just the way I like. Thanks everyone for your time. :)